# How to find all fixed points for this problem?

Tags: matrix-equations, fixed-points

Find all fixed points of the below function $$f:X\rightarrow X$$. 
$$X=R^N$$ and $$d(x,y)\equiv\Vert x-y\Vert_2$$ and $$f(x)\equiv Ax$$ where $$A\equiv
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 \\
    0 &1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$
Is it right to calculate all the intersection points of y=x and  y=Ax for this problem? How to justify this problem?

Comment: Yes. A fixed point is a point $\mathbf{x}\in X$ such that $f(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{x}$. So try and solve the equation $f(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{x}$.

Comment: what does X=R^N and d(x,y)≡∥x−y∥2 mean in this problem?

Comment: The $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ here refers to the domain of the function $f$ (basically what vectors you are allowed to input to the function). In this case, this is $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, i.e. 2D vectors (of the form $\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\end{bmatrix}$, where $x$ and $y$ are real numbers).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed points are defined by $Ax=x$. This gives $(x+y,y)=(x,y)$ which is true iff $y=0$. So points on the $x-$ axis are precisely the fixed points of $A$.

Comment: Thanks, what does d(x,y)≡∥x−y∥2 mean in this problem?

Comment: @king There is some redundant hypothesis in the question. You don't have to worry about $\|.\|_2$ at all because the question is purely algebraic.